# How to request to Server in ANDROID

Tags: java, android

How to Send request to server and read the response from the server in android. Not Coding. Just little explanation i want.

Comment: This is too broad and can't be reasonably answered with the way this site works. I recommend that you start with a tutorial and ask questions if you run into trouble.

Comment: Use the new library Volley ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean making a http request, check out this thread:

[Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

Comment: This isn't really a full answer.

Comment: @hexafraction What'd a proper answer look like, I wasn't even sure the OP really meant http requests. Just thought it'd be a pointer in the right direction in case he did mean http.

Comment: There really isn't a proper/full answer here that isn't a 20-page PDF. This is OK, however.\

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid this kind of questions which are already available on google and stackoverflow.!!.
You can create a webpage in php or any web technology and host it on server.
Full guidance you can get from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-networking/)

Comment: thnx :) . Actually i dont understand from where to start about "Send request to server and read the response from the server in android" ... hope this link help ..

Comment: Do you know android programming.? Any web programming?

Comment: i also know php, vb.net .. but new on Android

Comment: Then you must be knowing request-response. Android have HttpClient , HttpRequest etc.. classes for network operations . There are APIs on github for soap type request-response operations named as ksoap2-android library.